# Receiving and filtering UDP packets with the same destination port from multiple peers

Tags: linux, sockets, udp

I have two independent network peers sending video data over UDP to a single host both using the same destination port.

e.g.

```
protocol  src_addr  src_port   dst_addr  dst_port
UDP       peer1     ephemeral  host1     5555
UDP       peer2     ephemeral  host1     5555
```

I can have a single socket receive both streams and dispatch the video data to the appropriate decode engine based on `src_addr`; but what is the best way to achieve the same result *without* a single receive socket (which is desirable because I would prefer both decodes to be independent applications)?

It feels like it should be possible because each video data stream is uniquely identified in the table above.

The primary issue is that `bind()` fails when the two sockets, in the two separate receive applications, attempt to bind to the same port.

Options:

1) `SO_REUSEADDR` and `connect()`

Can I use `SO_REUSEADDR` to allow both sockets to bind to the same port? Will a subsequent call to `connect()` filter the appropriate datagrams to the appropriate application? Or will all datagrams still be delivered to the first socket?

2) `SO_REUSEPORT` and `connect()`

`SO_REUSEPORT` seems to be used to achieve the above for, as an example, load balancing. How is a receiving socket selected? And will it respect `connect()`?

A quick look at the code in the Linux kernel (`net/core/sock_reuseport.c`) suggests it is selected randomly unless a Berkeley packet filter is set.

3) Berkeley packet filter

Is this a sensible approach?